# Styling Bulleted list data added from a string.format

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I got a silly problem and need really your help: My application returns data from a LINQ query and presented on my page in bulletedlist like this:

```
var AvailableRooms =
from rm in AvailableRoomTable.AsEnumerable()
where !(rm.IsNull("RoomPrice"))

select new
{
    RoomType = rm.Field<String>("RoomType"),
    RoomPrice = rm.IsNull("RoomPrice") ? 0 : rm.Field<decimal>("RoomPrice"),
    AvailableRoom = rm.Field<int>("AvailableRooms")
};

foreach (var rm in AvailableRooms)
{
    string str2;
    if (QtyOfRooms <= Adults)
    {
        str2 = string.Format("{0},{1,20}", rm.RoomType, (rm.RoomType.Contains("Single") || (rm.RoomType.Contains("TwinBed")) ? RoomQueries.SingleRooms(Adults) : rm.RoomPrice * nights));
    }
    BulletedList2.Items.Add(str2);
}
```

I can get my data as follow:

Double , 1000.0000

Single , 222

Suite , 456.0000

TwinBed , 299

Now my problem is how to style the bulleted list and give it nicer look? I tried Jquery accordion but couldn't as I needed some div tag to be injected in my HTML at run time.

I was wondering if there is a better and easier way to bind my data. I can't bind with a gridview or on datatable as I only get the last line of my returned data. so the bulleted list seemed to work very well with the string.format. thank you for your suport.

Comment: And how to do want it to format like i.e. how should it look? BTW, have you consider using a Repeater control?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I tried a repeater but as I got many conditions(all returning the same string str2) the repeater didn't seem to be a good Idea. So I want my bulleted list to look like any of the simple jquery accordion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the repeater to get the [jQuery Accordion markup](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).

```
<div id="accordion">

    <asp:Repeater ID="rooms" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h3><a href="#"><%# Eval("RoomType") %></a></h3>
            <div>
                <span><%# Eval("RoomDesc") %></span>
                <span><%# Eval("AvailableRooms") %></span>
                <span><%# Eval("RoomPrice") %></span>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</div>
```

Comment: Jim thanks for your help. I tried that but the problem is that i have to output the same string (str2) from condition statements, and will have to create different repeaters for that. what I want is to format the string once and use it for all my conditions.